# Serial communication problem in QtSerial C++ - readLine()

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I’m currently working on GUI application for visualization data from STM32 MCU system. I’m using Qt6 libraries for C++, I’ve done sth similar in the past but in python. I’ve got a problem with receiving data, in python I used simple while loop looking like this:

```
import serial
port = 'COM4'
szybkosc = 115200
hSerial = serial.Serial(port, szybkosc, timeout = 1, parity = serial.PARITY_NONE, bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS)
hSerial.reset_input_buffer()
hSerial.flush()
while True:
   tmp = hSerial.readline()
   print(tmp)
```

I’ve been trying to implement sth very similar in C++ using `QSerialPort` Class:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QSerialPort>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QSerialPort m_SerialPort;
    m_SerialPort.setPortName("COM4");
    m_SerialPort.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
    m_SerialPort.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    m_SerialPort.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    m_SerialPort.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    m_SerialPort.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    m_SerialPort.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    m_SerialPort.flush();
    QByteArray buf;
    while (true){
        if(m_SerialPort.canReadLine()){
            buf = m_SerialPort.readLine();
            qInfo() << "Line: " + buf;
        }
    }
    qInfo() << "OUT!!!";
    return a.exec();
}
```

but I have a problem with `canReadLine()` function, it’s always false, so it never reads data, and if I omit the `if(m_SerialPort.canReadLine())` part of the code it’s always printing empty string. The while true loop and blocking functionality isn’t a problem in my application since the whole receiving part will be in different thread than the main one. The data send from the MCU is in JSON format ending with `‘\n’` so I really need to use `readLine()` function since the data won’t come in constant time interval.
Can someone please explain how to properly implement receiving data in that case? Thank you in advance  .

Comment: Since you don't start an event loop, Qt can not get the events. Make sure to start the Q(Core)Application event loop and properly connec to the readyRead() signal instead doing a blocking wait.

Comment: @chehrlic So i should move the QSerialPort m_SerialPort to a different class ald use connect?

Comment: No need for a class just to connect signals to slots but yes I would use a dedicated class